# if condition Check image width and height before upload with Javascript

Tags: jquery

How can I check, if condition while upload input type file.

```js
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  //alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
   if (this.width == 200 && this.width == 200) {
    form.submit();
   }
}
```

Comment: It would be `&& this.height == 200`. Also, I am not sure if you are allowed to `submit` a form without a button event for that.

Comment: @CatalinIancu : 'Oh my god...' it working thank you sir...